How does Exit Criteria in SFMC Journey Builder work when checking against Entry Data Extension?
I'm setting up a journey in SFMC, and I want to define exit criteria for when a subscriber is no longer present in the Data Extension that serves as the entry source. Specifically, I want to know if using Journey Data in the exit criteria, with the condition SubscriberKey IS NULL, will remove a contact from the journey if they are later removed from the entry Data Extension (but have already entered the journey).
Is this the correct approach? Or should I be using Contact Data instead to ensure that the subscriber exits the journey when they no longer exist in the entry source Data Extension? I want the user to automatically exit the journey if they are removed from the source Data Extension at any point after entry.
Thank you for your guidance!

It's different because I am asking about exit criteria with journey data, not contact data

Journey Data are not dependent on entry Data Extension, as the entry data is being cached in JB. Even if you delete the entry DE or remove the record, this will not be reflected in journey data.
